# Increasing nature of $\sec^{-1}x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In most of the textbooks, it is said that $\sec^{-1}x$ is a increasing function.

But my doubt is that $\sec^{-1}(-1)=\pi$ and $\sec^{-1}{1}=0$ which is violating the fundamental property of increasing function

$$f(x_1)<f(x_2)$$
$$x_1<x_2$$

Comment: yeah I know that, but still the property if $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, then $x_1<x_2$  should satisfy for all x in the domain.

Comment: What is the reason of downvote?

Comment: What does $\sec^1=0$ mean?

Comment: it was a typo, I corrected it

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/trigonometry/graphs-inversefunctions.php should explain the ambiguity

Comment: The textbooks should say it's *locally* increasing.

Comment: so by that logic, can we say $\tan x$ is locally increasing

Comment: Yes, we can – what's wrong with that?

Comment: but $\tan x$ is a periodic function

Comment: So, it's a locally increasing periodic function. I don't see any problem with that. For every $x$ in its domain, there's an open interval containing that $x$ such that the function is increasing over that interval. That's what I mean by locally increasing.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification: I assume with $\sec^{-1}$ you mean the inverse function.

Then let's study $\sec$ itself first: $\sec$ itself is is periodic with periode $2\pi$, having poles at $n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Due to the periodicity the $\sec$-function itself is not injective hence to consider an inverse function we have to restrict the definition area and usually the intervall $[0,\pi]\setminus{\left\{\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}}$ is considered.

On this intervall it holds: $$\sec: [0,\pi]\setminus{\left\{\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}} \to \Bbb{R}\setminus{(-1,1)}$$ but if we take a closer look to the part before and after the pole we get:

$$\sec: [0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \to [1,\infty)$$ and  $$\sec: (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi] \to (-\infty,-1]$$

What we see: The $\sec$ function has jumps at the poles.

Hence for the inverse it holds: 
$$\sec^{-1}:  [1,\infty)\to [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$ and  $$\sec^{-1}: (-\infty,-1] \to (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$$

With a jumps as well!
So while $\sec^{-1}(-1) = \pi$ the other part starts with $\sec^{-1}(1) = 0$

And we realize: Although it holds altogether that $$\sec^{-1}: \Bbb{R}\setminus{(-1,1)} \to [0,\pi]\setminus{\left\{\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}} $$ and $\sec^{-1}$ is strictly increasing on each of its definition areas, it jumps when crossing the non-defined area $(-1,1)$

Comment: yeah I know that, but still the property if $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, then $x_1<x_2$ should satisfy for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: No, obviously it doesn't. $\sec^{-1}$ is only strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,-1]$. It's differentiable on $\Bbb{R}\setminus{[-1,1]}$ and it's derivative is positive everywhere… but still it's not strictly increasing on the full area of definition.
It only is if you restrict it… so probably your author restrict it's definition area to $(-\infty,-1]$ or $[1,\infty)$?